# get BEST possible records after string comparison in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have to pass string to SQL to find BEST possible search results.

Ex :

Input string ='BEAUMONTS WAY EXTN'

In database have these values

```
+---+---------------+
| 1 | BENMORE       |
| 2 | NERISSA PLACE |
| 3 | BETTINA       |
| 4 | BEESTON       |
| 5 | KNOX          |
| 6 | MAIDA VALE    |
| 7 | BEAUMONT      |
| 8 | BEALASA       |
+---+---------------+
```

So output result must be

```
+---+----------+
| 1 | BEAUMONT |
| 2 | BEALASA  |
+---+----------+
```

In this comparison check upto 3 character and give result. input sting can be any thing so i can't use LIKE 'BEA%'.

Thank you in anticipation

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Column1
FROM Table
WHERE  CONTAINS(Column1, 'INPUT STRING')
```

Make sure to add the column(Column1) you want to search on is added to full text search index and then you can run full text queries for the text in the column. For more help on full text search visit [Full text search queries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx#queries).You can order your results based on most relevant i.e Rank